# Why was this question about clients reading HTTPS parameters migrated to Super User?

Tags: discussion, migration

The question ["Can HTTPS prameters be seen by the PC client?"](https://superuser.com/questions/1638797/can-https-request-parameters-be-seen-by-the-pc-client) was migrated to Super User, and I struggle to see why. It seems like an obvious fit for this site, on the format "can information X be seen by Y in situation Z". Had the question been asking how to do it, perhaps Super User would have been better.

Can someone explain this? I am starting to think I am missing something about the site scope?

Comment: In case anyone wounders, [the post is now returned to Security SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/246600/can-https-request-parameters-be-seen-by-the-pc-client).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would petition to migrate it back. SU is not the correct place. SO might *possibly* be, but it looks like a straight-up security question to me.

Comment: Thanks! I flagged it on SU.